# Process Array before displaying it

Tags: php, datatables

I am using Datatable to show rows form my database and I use this file

https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysqli

In my data base I have a table "table_name" inside it there are some rows:

```
"id" , "name" , "job" , "year_of_work"
"1" , "Adam" , "11", "14"
"2" , "Mark" , "14", "12"
"3" , "Erik" , "16", "16"
```

Job is just a reference, I have another table called "Jobs" and the following rows in it:

```
"id" , "Title" 
"11" , "Firman" 
"14" , "Mechanical" 
"16" , "Chef"
```

---

I am using datatable to view the content, it returns an array of data, I want to replace the number of the "job" with the jobe "name" witch is in another table.

I was able to do it " semi dynamic ! "

by changing this line

```
// General output
$row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

to this

```
// General output
 $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=='16' ) ? 'Chef' :  $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

The problem is when I do that when I do this change so row number 3 in my example shows like this!

```
 "3" , "Erik" , "Chef", "Chef"
```

any Ideas how to do it ?

`DataTable` initialization

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
      "aProcessing": true,
      "aServerSide": true,
      "ajax": "people-list.php",
      "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": [ 0 ],
        "data": null,
        "render": function ( data ) { return '<a href=people-page?id='+data[ 0 ]+' target="_blank">'+data[ 0 ]+'</a>'; }
      } ]
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: I forget to ask also I want it to be fully dynamic , so It should get the name of the job in job database

Comment: You need to show how you are setting up the plugin. I would use jQuery to edit table on the fly possibly. I have had to do this with datatables myself.

Comment: could you show us your query to retrieve your data ? I think you could deal with this by joining the job table.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
 "aProcessing": true,
 "aServerSide": true,
 
"ajax": "people-list.php",


          "columnDefs": [
          { "targets":  [ 0 ],
          "data": null,
          "render": function ( data ) {
            return '<a href=people-page?id='+data[ 0 ]+' target="_blank">'+data[ 0 ]+'</a>';
          }}
          ]
  
} );


} );
</script>

Comment: This was my jQuery file

Comment: @jiboulex , thanks, I will do it this way it is easier but how to use join in my case .. 

Im using Mysqli connection , I just need the select format " select * from .... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an SQL query in the php file that retrieves the data. You should `JOIN` the tables using the job id, include `title` from the job table in the select, and then use that property in the Datatable initialization.